# How to make my contact form work?

Tags: javascript, html, css, contact-form

I'm a beginner at web design, and I've just made my first site using html, css and a little bit of javascript. I have small contact form, and I wanna know is it possible to make it work without using PHP, bootstrap etc.
Here is my html code:

```
 <div class="form">
 <p>some text goes here<br>
 <br>some text here</p>
 <form action="#" method="post">
 <label for="form-name">Your name:</label> <input type="text" name="name" id="form-name" /><br>
 <label for="form-city">Your email:</label> <input type="text" name="city" id="form-city" /><br>
 <label for="form-story">Your message:</label><br />
 <textarea name="story" rows="5" cols="60" maxlenght="300" id="story> </textarea><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Send" />
 </form>
 </div>
```

Also, I think I made a mistake in "Your email:" section, so I'll be thankfull if you can help me with that too.
So, can anyone tell me what code do I need to make my contact form send me an email once my site is online?

Comment: You need a server side language to actually send the email

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. This question is asking for an entire solution rather than a specific programming issue that you can't solve and the code you have so far. Yes you have html, but that is not the code to send an e-mail. Like Danny said, you can't do this without some sort of server-side programming. It is very easy to download XAMPP and use online tutorials to learn PHP to do this, this is not the right website to ask for the entire solution. I would encourage you to look into XAMPP.

Comment: Why does it say "Your email:" for the city field?

Comment: Okay, thank you Danny and thank you @funkwurm, I didn't know that. I'll try to learn PHP and solve my own problem.

Comment: @k97513 Because I copied the code from something I did before for exercise, and now I'm not sure how to change it

Comment: @mockingjay_89 keep at it my friend, as other have mentioned I would laern the very basics of php as you are new to coding, you will be a pro in no time!

Comment: @mockingjay_89 all good man :) definitely don't wanna scare you away from StackOverflow, but at the same time the site is good because we uphold a certain type and level of questions and answers. Good luck man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to do this you would need to use a server side language such as PHP to process the form.

Answer (score 0):

HTML `<form>` elements are not automatically working. They're like a piece of paper. For this paper to get to you, you need to mail it, ie through a server side script. This is most commonly done with PHP. The form passes data a user enters to a PHP script through the `action` and `method` attributes:

```
<form action="page.php" method="post">
```

In that case, the information is being sent to the `page.php` page using a `POST` method. There are two types of methods generally used: `GET` and `POST`. `GET` sends the information through the URL (http://www.example.com/page.php?field1=someAnswer&field2=anotherAnswer), while `POST` sends it through the server as `$_SESSION` array. These individual values can be retrieved through `$_SESSION['field1']`. For your contact form, take a look at PHP's `mail` function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)